# Wingpanel suddenly shaded dark instead of changing fonts & icons to dark

Tags: wingpanel

I discovered a weird little problem, from which I think that other people had it too, but it was never resolved.

Before, when I switched the background image from a darker one to a light one, the behavior of the wingpanel was that the font color and the indicator icons changed from white to a dark color (close to black). But for some reason I don't know, this behavior suddenly changed: Now, if I switch to a light background image, the wingpanel switches from transparent to half transparent with black background, and the font and the indicator icons stay white.

It just changed this behavior without that I changed anything. Even more weird is: I just created a new user. And with the new user, the behavior is still the old one from before (so: when switching to a light background, the panel stays transparent but font and icons become dark).

So it seems, it must be something which changed on a user level. Actually, I liked the old behavior more. Any idea what the reason/issue could be?

Update: Unfortunately, this is happening again now after updating again. See my comment to the previously accepted answer below. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent update has this bug fix... Are you updated ?

It was happening to me, but gone after update

Comment: Ah, indeed! Just got a update notification, updated and now the problem is gone :)

Comment: Unfortunately, with the last update, the problem reappeared again. Now even worse: I always have the panel shaded dark now again, independent of the background image. If I create a new user, it is still everything working fine. Wish I knew what the cause for that could be... I already went through so many config folder in my home dir but couldn't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: A screenshot would be awesome... Elementary OS has dynamic panel anyway.

Comment: Well, the fix is very funny, that is - change the GTK theme in elementary tweaks with another one. You can download from Internet

Comment: This can't be the solution... It is obviously a bug, since the problem does not appear for a new user...

Comment: The last update size was 4.9mb. I am not getting anything like that, what I am getting is a dynamic bar. Is your wifi switch working properly? If I disable wifi in GUI, than it stuck at disable

Comment: After one of the last updates, it worked now again for me.

Comment: In case you get this problem again, disable the transparency by dconfig editor. (org>Pantheon>Desktop>Wingpanel)